# PublishSubject onError function in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, publish-subscribe, publishsubject

So, I am getting an error in my Android app (Kotlin) when trying to subscribe to a `PublishSubject`.

The error explanation is pretty straight forward, however, I have failed trying to implement this, `onError` function and I am not sure how to do it in a god way.

Here the error

```
The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling | com.androidnetworking.error.ANError
```

Here the PublishSubject:

```
var positionSubject = PublishSubject.create<Location>()
```

Here when I subscribe (which gives error inside the code of the subscription):

```
compositeDisposable.add(
                    positionSubject.subscribe {
                    // do some actions here that causes Exception
                    }
 )
```

Here my attempt to fix it in a "nice" way (did not work, still crashes in subscribe):

```
compositeDisposable.add(
                        positionSubject
                            .onErrorReturn { t -> 
                                 Log.d("debug", "EXCEPTION OCCURRED")
                                 Location("")}
                            .subscribe {
                        // do some actions here that causes Exception
                        }
     )
```

Here what I ended up doing to fix it and not crashing:

```
compositeDisposable.add(
                        positionSubject.subscribe {
                             try{
                                  // do some actions here that causes Exception
                             }catch(e:Exception){
                              Log.d("debug", "EXCEPTION OCCURRED $e")
                             }
                        
                        }
     )
```

I am wondering how to this in a cleaner way than using the try/catch block inside the subscribe, if it is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is `kotlin` way to subscribe a `PublishSubject`

```
var positionSubject = PublishSubject.create<Location>()
positionSubject.subscribe({ location ->
    
}, { error ->
    
})
```

This should work fine.

Comment: thanks! it was just a matter of writing it correctly in Kotlin!, it works fine!